# How to get around permissions error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run code that someone else wrote and having the following issue

```
# send to wellformedness
for file in os.listdir(input_directory):
    text = open(input_directory+file).read()
    wellformedness(text, file)
```

is giving me a PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\user\Documents\....\resources\txtcontrol_output'

Any ideas how to run this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have permissions to open the file?

Comment: You need to know the permissions of that file. It probably hasn't the permission to modified or read by other user than the one who created it. Run chmod in the directory containing the file to know about its permissions and change the mode to 777. There are many similar questions in this forum, you can around.

Comment: shamba and Joe: I made the empty folder txtcontrol_output just before running the code (becuase the issue before was that it couldn't find that folder).